# How to enable workspace switching selecting app in unity bar?

Tags: unity, 13.04, desktop-environments, workspace-switcher

Before upgrade to 13.04 when I selected an application icon in the Unity Bar the desktop changed to the workspace in wich that app window was?

Now I can't do it. How can I enable this option again?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have to do with the workspace switcher being switched off by default now. To re-enable it pop into:

System Settings -> Appearance -> Select the 'Behaviour' Tab -> tick the 'Enable workspaces' box

[image]

The workspace switcher should now reappear on the Unity bar

Comment: I have the workspace switcher already enabled. The workspace switcher works an I can switch between them. Is just by clicking in the icon of an active program that the workspaces don't switch.

Comment: I misunderstood, my apologies. From my experience, if windows are not maximised sometime they ignore the clicks because there may be a slight overlap between workspaces. Does the switcher function work? (Alt-tab by default). If you can select windows that way it would be a start. Also, do you have CCSM installed? in 'general options -> focus & raise behaviour' the option 'click to focus' should be checked.

Comment: Alt+Tab neither works and 'click on focus' is checked

Comment: Maybe try and reset Unity to its default settings then? The easiest way would be to install unity-tweak-tool. After that open a terminal and run the command [unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity]

Comment: Tried this: sudo unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity  as suggested by  @Victor9098, but hanged halfway through with errors. Think my system was broke somewhere. So I uninstalled and reinstalled unity using SYNAPTIC PACKAGE MANAGER.. starting switching apps ok... Thanks